# Custom MassTransit Error Handling

Tags: .net, masstransit

When configuring a new MassTransit v2 IServiceBus, is there any extensibility point to add your own error-logging callback?  I am using the log4net extender, but I would like to integrate an unsupported logger (RayGun), specifically to log exceptions after a message is sent to the error queue.

It would be handy to know:

- When an exception is raised
- When the specified number of retries has occurred, and MT is giving up

Comment: Raise an exception to where? If the exception ends up at MT, that can cause problems. If you just want logging, you can implement your own logger as you suggested. But I would avoid raising exceptions from logging code - logging should NEVER throw an exception -- ever.

Comment: Gah!, I meant 'to log exceptions'.
e.g.
1. The database is down, so my code throws an Exception. 
2. MassTransit captures the exception.  I would like to know about this
3. MassTransit retries n times
4. MassTransit gives up, and sends message to the error queue.  I would also like to know about this

Comment: You could add a log4net appender, or you could plug in to the logging support in MT the way NLog and Log4Net are done. A log4net appender would likely have more longevity and work with other applications as well.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a CompoundLog & CompoundLogger class to allow new to add multiple ILogs. Gist to follow tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson In fact, a log4net appender is much nicer.  I am using that anyway and it means a lot less code.  Thanks!